# Disable Paste on React Native TextInput

Tags: react-native, textinput

Nothing in the docs about this. I want to disable the small popup below when clicking on a TextInput in React Native.

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is iOS only right? I'm pretty sure if you hide your caret the popup also stops showing up. Try setting your textfield's caretHidden prop as true* and check if it works out for you.

Comment: If possible, I would like the caret to be shown, only the popup to be disabled.

Comment: I'm looking for this exact issue too. Hopefully we can figure it out! Definitely post the solution if you come across it.

Comment: I've currently got a PR out that adds this ability for iOS. Hopefully it can get reviewed/merged soon! https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/16847

Answer (score 10):

```
<TextInput
   contextMenuHidden={true}
   value={this.state.text}
   onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text})}
/>
```

Comment: It does not work. i can still see context menu on double tap

Answer (score 3):

for ios

```
<TextInput contextMenuHidden={true}
```

for Android

```
<View removeClippedSubviews={true}>

  <TextInput contextMenuHidden={true} />

</View>
```

[Surender Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5479089/surender-kumar)'s answer:
[React Native 55.4: contextMenuHidden does not hide menu on Android - Disable Options on React-Native Text Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650556/react-native-55-4-contextmenuhidden-does-not-hide-menu-on-android-disable-opt/62513034#62513034)

Answer (score 2):

for stop copy paste the following code is

```
 <TextInput contextMenuHidden={true}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution works for me. I am clearing keyboard on onTouchEnd event

```
const [text1, setText1] = useState('')
    
const clearClipboard = () =>{
 Clipboard.setString('')
}
    
const onChangeText = (text) =>{
 //For android 12+ clipboard autofill option, dont allow text change more than one char..which means user is typing.
 if(text1.length+1 >= text.length){
  setText1(text)
 }
}
    
<TextInput onChangeText={onChangeText} value={text1} contextMenuHidden={true} onTouchEnd={clearClipboard}></TextInput>
```