# React Native 55.4: contextMenuHidden does not hide menu on Android - Disable Options on React-Native Text Input

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using a [recently added (in v0.55.4)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/2dd2529b3ab3ace39136a6e24c09f80ae421a17e) prop to `TextInput`  called `contextMenuHidden`. When I add this prop to a TextInput component it seems to disable copy and paste for iOS but not for Android.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there another step that needs to happen to get this to disable copy and paste on android?

```
  <TextInput
    style={...}
    onChangeText={...}
    value={...}
    contextMenuHidden={true}
  />
```

Comment: There is no solution you have to extend react native (native module) and add it

Answer (score 0):

for ios

```
<TextInput contextMenuHidden={true}
```

for Android

```
<View removeClippedSubviews={true}>

  <TextInput contextMenuHidden={true} />

</View>
```

Comment: Still appearing context menu on android!!!

Comment: yeah this doesn't seem to work