# How to disable Paste (Ctrl+V) and Copy(Ctrl+C)in a TextField of MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I disable Paste (Ctrl+V) and Copy (Ctrl+C) option  in one of my TextFields of MaterialUI?

Iḿ using ReactJs

Comment: this stackoverflow might have your answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805803/disable-copy-paste-in-html-input-fields
or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790050/disable-paste-on-react-native-textinput?rq=1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

onCopy onCut onPaste are clipboard events.
The below code is the sample.

The reference in react docs is below.

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#clipboard-events

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
```

```
    <TextField
      value={val}
      onCut={handleChange}
      onCopy={handleChange}
      onPaste={handleChange}
     />
```

Comment: thank you very much @Velu S Gautam, it helped me a lo

Comment: does this work on phone?